# accept phone numbers of specific characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

In SQL Server, I want a code that allows to accept phone numbers starting with `056` or `078` and have a total of 9-10 digits.

I tried:

```
 WHERE 
   (SUBSTRACT([mobile], 1 , 3 ) in (056, 078) )
and (len([mobile]) between 9 and 10))
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: What is `SUBSTRACT`? Or did you mean `[SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: yes Substring , neither substring nor substr do work

Comment: And `(056, 078)` is a set of numbers, you probably need strings: `('056', '078')` (numeric comparison is not going to give you the right result: phone numbers are not numbers is any useful sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE LEFT([mobile], 3) IN ('056', '078')
    AND LEN([mobile]) IN (9, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Select * From dbo.Table Where Left([PhoneNo],3) In('056', '078') And Len(PhoneNo) = 
  10 And IsNumeric(PhoneNO) = 1
```